# Method Type "OPTION" instead of "GET" with $resource Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a call to the Restful Api using $resource with the below mentioned code. On the network tab, I found out the Method type is "OPTION" instead of "GET" and type "text/html" (only when I add custom headers). If I remove the run code block, all work fine. But I have to add those headers, any idea?

```
 app.run(['$route', '$http', function ($route, $http) {

        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-User'] = 'user';
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Password'] = 'password';
    }]);

var resource = $resource('api', {});


 var deffered = $q.defer();

            resource.query({
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,

            }, function (data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            }, function (status) {

                deffered.reject(status);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
```

Comment: this is how browser work - CORS is your google query...

Comment: Any suggestion to resolve this? My calls keep getting failed

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure the API to handle the preflight OPTIONS request or use a reverse proxy to avoid CORS altogether.

Comment: unfortuntely I don't have an access to the API. What did you mean by using a reverse proxy to avoid CORS?

Comment: Did my answer help you to solve your problem? If not, provide comments or update your question with edits.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

A simple cross-site request, which does not require an OPTIONS preflight, is one that:

> Only uses GET, HEAD or POST. If POST is used to send data to the
> server, the Content-Type of the data sent to the server with the HTTP
> POST request is one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
> multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
>
> Does not set custom headers with
> the HTTP Request (such as X-Modified, etc.)

(From [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) article on MDN)

Your request fails the second criteria (ie. it adds headers), so it can't be sent by your browser without an OPTIONS preflight.

#### Solutions

- Configure your API to handle OPTIONS (as per your own comment, it sounds like you can't do this)
- Setup a reverse proxy, a web server to handle your requests itself, returning the results it receives from the API endpoint you're attempting to get data from

How you do the latter is highly dependent upon what type of web server you can setup and where (e.g. Do you use Node? nginx? Apache? Will the proxy be hosted on the same domain as your client app?), so you'll have to research the topic of "reverse proxy CORS" on the web with your situation in mind.